# Sum columns in numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a 2D NumPy array `V`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

V = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(6,8))
```

This gives `V` as:

```
[[ -1  -6   5 -10   7   6   7  -2]
 [ -1 -10   0  -2  -6   9   6  -6]
 [  5   1   1  -9  -2  -6   4   7]
 [  9   3  -5   3   9   3   2  -9]
 [ -6   8   3   1   0  -1   5   8]
 [  6  -3   1   7   4  -3   1  -9]]
```

Now, I have 2 lists, `r1` and `r2`, containing column indices as follows:

```
r1 = [1, 2, 5]
r2 = [3, 4, 7]
```

What I want is to add the columns of `V` based on the indices pair `(r1, r2)` and store it in column indices `r1`. That is, for this case, add columns `(1, 3)`, `(2, 4)` and `(5, 7)` and store them respectively in columns `1`, `2` and `5` of `V`.

It can be done easily like this:

```
V[:, 1] = V[:, [1,3]].sum(axis=1)
V[:, 2] = V[:, [2,4]].sum(axis=1)
V[:, 5] = V[:, [5,7]].sum(axis=1)
```

which gives `V` as:

```
[[ -1 -16  12 -10   7   4   7  -2]
 [ -1 -12  -6  -2  -6   3   6  -6]
 [  5  -8  -1  -9  -2   1   4   7]
 [  9   6   4   3   9  -6   2  -9]
 [ -6   9   3   1   0   7   5   8]
 [  6   4   5   7   4 -12   1  -9]]
```

My concern is that is there a way **we can do it without loops?** Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `V[:, r2]` at `V[:, r2]`, like below:

```
V[:, r1] += V[:, r2]
print(V)
```

**Output**

```
[[ -1 -16  12 -10   7   4   7  -2]
 [ -1 -12  -6  -2  -6   3   6  -6]
 [  5  -8  -1  -9  -2   1   4   7]
 [  9   6   4   3   9  -6   2  -9]
 [ -6   9   3   1   0   7   5   8]
 [  6   4   5   7   4 -12   1  -9]]
```